# Why text dimensions are 0 when SVG width or height is 0?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to calculate SVG text dimensions by creating an SVG with `width = 0` and `height = 0` (so it won't be visible, and won't affect the layout).

Chrome has no problem with this, and I get `{width: 35.546875, height: 18.5}`.

However, Firefox "doesn't like" the fact that SVG's `width` or `height` is `0`, and I get `{ width: 0, height: 0 }`.

Which one is the expected behavior by spec?

How would you solve this cross browser issue?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const text = document.getElementById('text');
  const { width, height } = text.getBoundingClientRect();

  console.log({ width, height });
});
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <text id="text">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/yXjNYj?editors=1010)

Comment: _“How would you solve this cross browser issue?”_ – by not setting width and height to 0 in the first place ... there are other methods of “hiding” content from the user, while still getting it rendered properly; such as absolute positioning outside the top left corner of the document (other placement might cause scrollbars on the document), or placing it inside an 1*1px element with its overflow cut off, ...

Comment: I was starting to answer with [`text.getBBox()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) and the neccessary caveats about local and screen coordinate systems, but after experimenting I find that the height values differ between Chrome and Firefox. It seems Firefox always gives the same height for all glyphs, while Chrome takes the existence of descenders into account, but not ascenders: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZjLNv?editors=1010